# Route [payments-data] not defined in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel-5, datatables

I am trying to use jquery datatables to output some data from a mysql database.

Here is my route:

`Route::get('datatables', ['as' => 'HomeController', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex']);
Route::get('payments-data', ['as' => 'HomeControllerPaymentsData', 'uses' => 'HomeController@Payments']);`

My controller `HomeController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class HomeController extends Controller
{


    public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('payments');
    }

    /**
     * Process datatables ajax request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function Payments()
    {
        return Datatables::of(DB::table('Payment'))->make(true);
    }
```

Here is my blade/view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover" id="payments-table">


                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            @push('scripts')
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    $('#payments-table').DataTable({
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        scrollX: true,
                        ajax: '{!! route('payments-data') !!}',
                        columns: [
                            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                            { data: 'amount', name: 'amount' },
                        ]
                    });
                });
            </script>
           @endpush    
           @endsection
```

However, when I try to run the route `/datatables` I get Route `[payments-data] not defined. (View: /home/bob/Desktop/dibon/resources/views/payments.blade.php)` What could be doing wrong? Anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{!! route('HomeControllerPaymentsData') !!}` as defined in `Route::get('payments-data', ['as' => 'HomeControllerPaymentsData', 'uses' => 'HomeController@Payments']);`.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Worked!